# How can I perform click on input using xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I have used the below code to click the element.But it failed to locate the element and shows element not visible.

```
elem3=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='check-box']")
elem3.click()
```

The html code:

```
<span id="Some-span" class="urCWhl" title="Indicator">
<input id="check-box" class="urC" type="checkbox" hidefocus="hidefocus" ti="-1" tabindex="-1" ct="C"/>
<span id="label-lbl" class="name_class" style="width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;" unselectable="on" f="some-id" ti="0" tabindex="0" title="Indicator"></span>
```

Comment: Your finder is correct, unless you should wait until it's being visible...:)

Comment: element is already there

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Post full stack trace. What's the framework the app is built on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='check-box']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input might be inside a frame? If so switch to that frame by doing:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('framename')
```

or if not, try to find via id then click the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('check-box').click()
```

one thing to remember is that if the checkbox is already have a value, if you click the checkbox, the check will be removed. if you want to have the checkbox to have a true value always, you may do this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('check-box').setAttribute('checked','');")
```

This will execute a javascript to always have a true value on the checkbox